# Global error with ng-options. How?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have stumbled upon the most puzzling bug I have had in my project for a long time: I broke `ng-options`.

What do I mean by that?

I mean that **EVERY** `select` in my entire project that uses `ng-options` is not working, and I don't know what caused it (I've been backing out changes all morning)!

Here is the behavior:

I have my `ng-options`:

```
$scope.fileComparisonMethods = [
    {
        name: 'MD5',
        value: 0
    },
    {
        name: 'SHA1',
        value: 1
    },
    {
        name: 'SHA256',
        value: 2
    },
    {
        name: 'SHA384',
        value: 4
    },
    {
        name: 'SHA512',
        value: 5
    },
    {
        name: 'RIPEMD',
        value: 3
    }
];
```

..and my `ng-model`:

```
$scope.comparisonMethod = $scope.fileComparisonMethods[0].value;
```

..and here is my `select`:

```
<select ng-model="comparisonMethod" ng-options="option.value as option.name for option in fileComparisonMethods" class="form-control input-small" />
```

My `select` populates with the proper options, yet selecting any of the options does not update the `ng-model`. If I place an `ng-change` on my `select`, the `ng-change` will not be called.

Now, if I initialize my `ng-model` to a value not present in my `ng-options`:

```
$scope.comparisonMethod = -1;
```

...and place an `ng-change` on my select:

```
<select ng-model="comparisonMethod" ng-options="option.value as option.name for option in fileComparisonMethods" ng-change="changeHappened()" class="form-control input-small" />
```

..then my `ng-change` will be called on the first selection, the `ng-model` will not be updated, and the `ng-change` will not fire on any following selections.

Weird right?

Lastly, if I write my `select` without `ng-options` instead:

```
<select ng-model="comparisonMethod" class="form-control input-small">
    <option value=0>MD5</option>
    <option value=1>SHA1</option>
    <option value=2>SHA256</option>
    <option value=4>SHA384</option>
    <option value=5>SHA512</option>
    <option value=3>RIPEMD</option>
</select>
```

..everything works just fine! So what happened to `ng-options`?! What did I do?!

Remember, this suddenly happened to **EVERY** `select` that uses `ng-options` in my project, so **something happened with `ng-options` globally**. What could cause this behavior.

I have been unable to replicate this issue in a JSFiddle or Plunkr. Sorry.

**UPDATE 2015-14-12 20:13:00**
This issue is only happening in Chrome version `47.0.2526.80 m` and Opera version `34.0.2036.25`, the most current version of these browsers at this time. From what I can find, this version was released on Dec. 1st. This issue **does not** occur in Chrome version `47.0.2526.73`, `IE 11.0.9600.18125`, Firefox version `42.0 build 20151029151421`, or (the latest build of) Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this issue is known and was repaired by AngularJS ([see the Chromium post here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=565132)). Take note that in my post I am using Angular 1.2.3. I have now upgraded (painlessly I might add) to Angular 1.4.8. Upgrading to the latest version of Angular solved my issue.